# statsmodel time series analysis - using AR model with differing lags between endogenous and exogenous variables

Tags: python, time, statistics, series, statsmodels

I am trying to build an ARDL model in python, where I have a model given as:

y = b0 + b1^t-1 + b2^t-2 + ... b5^t-5 + a1^x-1

In other words, a time series model with 5 autoregressive lagged terms, and 1 exogenous lag.

I tried using statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA, which allows for exogenous variables, and I get an output with the following variables:

const, x1, ar.L1.y, ar.L2.y, ar.L3.y, ar.L4.y, ar.L5.y

the code i used to get these variables is

> model = ARMA(endog=returns, order=(ar_order, 0, exog_order), exog=exog_returns)

> model_fit = model.fit()

> print(model_fit.summary())

based on the coefficient value of x1, I assume this isn't 1 time lag prior, but rather the value of the exogenous variables influence as a whole.

Is there anyway to specify I just want the model to use 1 time lag for the exogenous variable in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ARMA` is it deprecated.  Either use `SARIMAX` or `AutoReg`.

The key to using exog variables is to make sure they are aligned to the y data they affect.  Here I shift `x` by 1 so that it is as if the lag of x is driving y.

If using AutoReg, you can do

```py
from statsmodels.tsa.api import AutoReg
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rg = np.random.default_rng(0)
idx = pd.date_range("1999-12-31",freq="M",periods=100)
x = pd.DataFrame({"x":rg.standard_normal(100)}, index=idx)
x = x.shift(1) # lag x
y = x @ np.ones((1,)) + rg.standard_normal(100)
# Drop first obs which is NaN
y = y.iloc[1:]
x = x.iloc[1:]

# 5 lags and exogenous regressors
res = AutoReg(y,5, exog=x, old_names=False).fit()

# Summary
res.summary()
```

This produces

```
                            AutoReg Model Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   99
Model:                   AutoReg-X(5)   Log Likelihood                -127.520
Method:               Conditional MLE   S.D. of innovations              0.940
Date:                Mon, 01 Mar 2021   AIC                              0.046
Time:                        14:57:44   BIC                              0.262
Sample:                    06-30-2000   HQIC                             0.133
                         - 03-31-2008
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -0.0500      0.098     -0.512      0.609      -0.241       0.141
y.L1          -0.0342      0.070     -0.486      0.627      -0.172       0.104
y.L2           0.0621      0.070      0.884      0.377      -0.076       0.200
y.L3          -0.0715      0.071     -1.009      0.313      -0.210       0.067
y.L4          -0.0941      0.070     -1.347      0.178      -0.231       0.043
y.L5          -0.0323      0.071     -0.453      0.651      -0.172       0.107
x              1.0650      0.103     10.304      0.000       0.862       1.268
                                    Roots
=============================================================================
                  Real          Imaginary           Modulus         Frequency
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AR.1            1.1584           -1.0801j            1.5838           -0.1194
AR.2            1.1584           +1.0801j            1.5838            0.1194
AR.3           -1.3814           -1.7595j            2.2370           -0.3559
AR.4           -1.3814           +1.7595j            2.2370            0.3559
AR.5           -2.4649           -0.0000j            2.4649           -0.5000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. So, is it correct to say that the x coefficient is just 1 time lag, or is it something different? Because I see similar coefficient values to what you have in your model summary. It seems surprising to me that if it was just 1 time lag, the value of the coefficient would be so significant. I had assumed X was representative of the entire exogenous time series some how..

Comment: The X is just a time lag.  When setting up an exog set of regressors, the model looks a lot like OLS, but then has some AR terms.  If you can estimate your model as an ARDL(0,Q) using `OLS(y,exog)`, so that exog really contains the lagged values of x, then you can estimate it as an ARDL(P,Q) as `AutoReg(y,lags=P,exog)`.   

That the coefficient has a standard err of 0.1 here is completely determined by the fact that x has variance 1 and the residual has variance 1, so the parameter variance 1*(sum(t=2)^100 1**2)^(-1) = 1/99. This is just what comes out of OLS.